# how to get file uploaded by ckfinder and sent by email?

Tags: php, ckeditor, symfony-1.4, ckfinder

I have a problem in my symfony 1.4 using CKFinder. My CKFinder is used to create a custom message for email template. But now I need to put an attached piece in the mail. So I saw the CKEditor can help me to do this. I activate the file in CKFinder and I can upload a file in the server.

But after sending my email the link which created in the message was not good. I have in the page this message: "Cannot GET /js/ckfinder/userfiles/files/myfile.pdf "

So I try an other url with the path of my application (like this "http: //localhost/web/js/ckfinder/userfiles/files/myfile.pdf" in localhost. But he redirect me on login page in my application.

I try to find the best url to access at my file but unfortunately I failed :(.

Someone can help me please ?? I have no more idea to resolve my problem.

I have this parameters in config.php:

```
$baseUrl = '/js/ckfinder/userfiles/';
```

`$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);`;

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Files',              // Single quotes not allowed
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'files',
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'files',
    'maxSize' => "16M",
    'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
    'role' => '*',
    'resourceType' => '*',
    'folder' => '/',

    'folderView' => true,
    'folderCreate' => true,
    'folderRename' => true,
    'folderDelete' => true,

    'fileView' => true,
    'fileUpload' => true,
    'fileRename' => true,
    'fileDelete' => true);
```